# How can I save my application now-oauth and HTTPS?

Tags: facebook, oauth

Well, I am a non-Facebook developer, and a normal .NET programmer who have created a Facebook application for a regular website around one year ago using [FBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#FBML). I have no time to read the roadmap every day and know what will be next. So I had no idea about [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and HTTPS till yesterday.

All of a sudden I received an email yesterday saying (27 Sep) upgrade to OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS,
otherwise the application will be disabled from 1st Oct.

Now, I read about OAuth 2.0 the whole day yesterday, and think I can get around it now chaining things, but I found that the site which currently host my Facebook application doesn't have SSL (HTTPS support) or dedicated IP address and I found that I need to invest around 20$ to get SSL and another $20 for a dedicated IP address. I am ready to pay 
for it, but as you know a response from hosting are not that quick.

Now I have emailed my hosting to make arrangement for it, but sadly they have not responded yet, and I now only have one day left (I don't know they will respond or not).

So how can I save my application? I don't have any server that support HTTPS for now. Even if I get some free SSL I am not able to implement it as I don't have a dedicated IP address.

Is there some way I can put a "will be back soon" kind of message. Or how can I save the application now?

I think I need to update that HTTPS canvas page in the setting anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

FBML applications are not required to migrate and support HTTPS and signed requests.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/567/

Also, be aware that Facebook will stop supporting FBML apps at the end of the year.